# Speeding up construction of simple tridiagonal matrix

Tags: performance-tuning, packed-arrays, sparse-arrays

I have the following code to construct a tridiagonal matrix:

```
ClearAll[th];
th[nwells_ /; EvenQ@nwells] := Module[
  {size = nwells, bdiag},
  bdiag = RandomReal[{0, 99}, size - 1];
  SparseArray[
   {
    Band[{1, 1}] -> bdiag,
    Band[{1, 2}] -> -0.5,
    Band[{2, 1}] -> -0.5},
   {size - 1, size - 1}
   ]
  ]
```

This will be executed millions of times (`bdiag` is actually something that will change each time, so this is unavoidable). I'd like to speed it up as much as possible. Any ideas? I am interested in values of `nwells` of the order of 100 to 1000.

EDIT: Let us compare the time taken by the `Band` version, by MrW's version and Rojo's version for varying sizes:

```
{
  Table[{i, Do[th[i], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {i, 100, 
    5000, 200}],
  Table[{i, Do[banded[i], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {i, 100,
     5000, 200}],
Table[{i, Do[banded2[i], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {i, 100,
         5000, 200}]
  } // ListLogPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"size", "t"}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(the slowest one is mine). Note the logarithmic axis. Evidently, the `Band` method falls behind more and more with larger system sizes.

Also, using `Band` [unpacks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3497/16):

```
On["Packing"]
th[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
banded[3000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This occurs when `Band` is used to insert the (packed) `bdiag` list into the diagonal.

Comment: The fastest solution is: `th[nwells_ /; EvenQ@nwells, theta_] :=
 Module[{size = nwells, bdiag, boffdiag},
  boffdiag = SparseArray[{}, size - 2, -0.5];
  bdiag = RandomReal[99, size - 1];
  SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> bdiag[[i]]}, size - {1, 1}] +
   Sum[DiagonalMatrix[boffdiag, i], {i, {-1, 1}}]
  ]`... [hurr hurr :D](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6469540#6469540)

Comment: @rm-rf a man dare not have a life to keep pace with you ;-p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question came up in Chat the other day.  Here is the solution I proposed.

```
banded[n_Integer?EvenQ] :=
  With[
   {main = RandomReal[99, n - 1],
    side = SparseArray[{}, n - 2, -0.5]},
   SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> main[[i]], n - 1] +
    Sum[side ~DiagonalMatrix~ i, {i, {-1, 1}}]
  ]
```

This uses several tricks and observations.  Credit for the first goes to [Norbert Pozar](http://old.nabble.com/-mg106980--Band-too-slow-when-constructing-a-SparseArray-td27383767.html), who showed me that this is a very fast way to construct a diagonal SparseArray from a list `x`:

```
SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> x[[i]], Length @ x]
```

The second is my own observation that a `DiagonalMatrix` made from a `SparseArray` list is also created quickly.  This in enhanced by  creating the list with `SparseArray[{}, n - 2, -0.5]`, where the "background" of the array is the element to be repeated, rather than `ConstantArray` or `Table`.  One can see below that only minimal evaluation takes place:

```
SparseArray[{}, 10^6, -0.5] // InputForm
```

> ```
> SparseArray[Automatic, {1000000}, -0.5, {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, {}}]
> ```

DiagonalMatrix is particularly fast with this input form.

These "tricks" are combined with the knowledge that adding sparse SparseArrays is fast, and that `Band` can be rather slow (again thanks to Norbert Pozar) to create a solution that is about fifty times faster than the original.

Comment: Maybe part of the speed difference is related to unpacking? Also, it appears that how faster this is (faster than `Band`) depends on the system size--see update in my question. I wonder why.

Answer (score 8):

Given the millions of times that code will be run, for a size range of about 1000, all I could think to speed up @Mr.Wizard 's code is to memoize what stays fixed

```
i : diags[n_] := 
  i = With[{side = SparseArray[{}, n - 2, -0.5]}, 
    Sum[side~DiagonalMatrix~i, {i, {-1, 1}}]];

banded2[n_Integer?EvenQ] := 
 With[{main = RandomReal[99, n - 1]}, 
  SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> main[[i]], n - 1] + diags[n]]
```

Comparing the two

```
{Table[{i, Do[banded2[i], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {i, 100,
     5000, 200}], 
  Table[{i, Do[banded[i], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {i, 100,
     5000, 200}]} // ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"size", "t"}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good addition. +1