# Adding and subtracting from elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to solve an aparently simple problem.

Given a list of length `n`, `{a1,b1,c1,d1...}` I want to perform two simple operations, and form a new list from each one: `{a1+1,b1-1,c1,d1...}`, `{a1,b1+1,c1-1,d1...}`, `{a1,b1,c1+1,d1-1...}` and so on, and `{a1-1,b1+1,c1,d1...}` and so on.

The list elements must not be greater or less than certain values after the addition or substraction. In `{a1+1,b1-1,c1,d1...}`, `{a1,b1+1,c1-1,d1...}`, `{a1,b1,c1+1,d1-1...}` each element must be constrained: `a1<max` and `b1>0`, `b1<max` and `c1>0`, etc.

Using this lists I finally use the original list and the `n` new lists to get a list of the form: `{Join[list,new1],Join[list,new2],...}`

To solve this problem I wrote a code that although works, takes a very long time to calculate for several sets of list  `{{a1,b1,c1,d1...}, {a2,b2,c2,d2...}...}`. Here I post an example using only a list with two sublists, with four elements each one: `{{1, 2, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}}`

```
lst1 = {{1, 2, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}};
dim = Partition[Range[Length@First@lst1], 2, 1];
list = li[]; (*to save the "composed" lists*)

(lst = #;
lst2 = Partition[lst, 2, 1];

lst31 = MapThread[If[#1 < 2 && #2 > 0, {#1 + 1, #2 - 1}, {#1, #2}] &,Transpose@lst2];
lst41 = Union@MapThread[ReplacePart[lst, {#1[[1]]-> #2[[1]], #1[[2]]-> #2[[2]]}]&, {dim,lst31}];

lst32 = MapThread[If[#1 > 0 && #2 < 2, {#1 - 1, #2 + 1}, {#1, #2}]&,Transpose@lst2];
lst42 = Union@MapThread[ReplacePart[lst, {#1[[1]]-> #2[[1]], #1[[2]]-> #2[[2]]}]&, {dim, lst32}];

lst61 = Join[lst, #] & /@ lst41;
lst62 = Join[lst, #] & /@ lst42;
lst6 = Union@Join[lst61, lst62];
list = li[list, lst6];
) & /@ lst1;

list = List @@ Flatten@list
```

Any advice to improve the performance of the code would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

Based on comments, I tried to explain better the second part of my problem giving a numerical example.

**Edit 2**

I have added a more precise description about the constraints of the elements of the lists.

Comment: Could you give a numerical example of your composed lists? I'm not sure I understand what you mean there.

Comment: Hi! I already put in there a numerical example. Thanks!

Comment: kurush, I looked at your code again and I am wondering if it really is working as you intend.  For example, should there be `{1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2}` in the output for the first input list?  What about these for the second?:  `{{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1}}`

Comment: That's weird. I'm getting from the first input list `{{1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 
   2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2}}` and from the second one `{{2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {2,
    2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,
    2, 0}}` as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand the second part of your question so I shall address the first.
Here is a method that should be reasonably fast and versatile.

```
lst = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
n = Length @ lst;
offsets = NestList[RotateRight, PadRight[{1, -1}, n], n - 2];
lst2 = lst + # & /@ offsets;

lst2 // Column
```

> ```
> {1+a,-1+b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}
> {a,1+b,-1+c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}
> {a,b,1+c,-1+d,e,f,g,h,i,j}
> {a,b,c,1+d,-1+e,f,g,h,i,j}
> {a,b,c,d,1+e,-1+f,g,h,i,j}
> {a,b,c,d,e,1+f,-1+g,h,i,j}
> {a,b,c,d,e,f,1+g,-1+h,i,j}
> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,1+h,-1+i,j}
> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,1+i,-1+j}
> ```

---

Here is a faster method based on techniques described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13008/121).

```
lst = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
n = Length @ lst;
offsets = Sum[DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[{}, n - 1, 1 - 2 i], i, {n - 1, n}], {i, 0, 1}];
lst2 = ConstantArray[lst, n - 1] + offsets;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the original post I already put a better explanation of the second part of the question. However, is there some way to put constraints in the values of the lists elements? If you have `{...a+1,b-1...}` exclude results if `a` is greater than a certain value (say 2) or if `b` is less than a certain value (say 0)?

Comment: Well, thanks. Your suggestions really improved the performance of my code.

Comment: @kurush Sorry, I somehow didn't see the update to your question until I noticed the Accept. (Thanks.) Let me see if I understand this right: if the additions or subtractions on any specific element would cause it to be outside the interval [0, 2] the original value should be used instead.  Is that correct?  Are you inputs always integer valued lists?  If so we can efficiently use `Clip`.  Let me know and I'll update my answer either way.

Comment: Yes, that's the part of my code `MapThread[If[#1 < max && #2 > min, {#1 + 1, #2 - 1}, {#1, #2}] &,Transpose@lst2]`. If the elements are outside the interval defined by `[min,max]` then the program returns the default value. And yes, they are always integers. In my version using your suggestions this part stayed untouched.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness (since it's also mentioned in the link provided by Mr. Wizard), here is an approach using `Band`:

```
lst = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
Outer[Times, Most[1 & /@ lst], lst] + 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {# - 1, #} &@
   Length[lst]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  \text{a}+1 & \text{b}-1 & \text{c}
>    & \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f}
>    & \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i}
>    & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b}+1 & \text{c}-1
>    & \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f}
>    & \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i}
>    & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c}+1 &
>    \text{d}-1 & \text{e} & \text{f}
>    & \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i}
>    & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d}+1 & \text{e}-1 &
>    \text{f} & \text{g} & \text{h} &
>    \text{i} & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d} & \text{e}+1 &
>    \text{f}-1 & \text{g} & \text{h}
>    & \text{i} & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f}+1
>    & \text{g}-1 & \text{h} &
>    \text{i} & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} &
>    \text{g}+1 & \text{h}-1 &
>    \text{i} & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} &
>    \text{g} & \text{h}+1 &
>    \text{i}-1 & \text{j} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} &
>    \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} &
>    \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i}+1
>    & \text{j}-1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: `Outer[Times, Most[1 & /@ lst], lst]` seems wasteful; why did you choose that?

Comment: What's wrong with Outer[ ] in this context? Is there a slicker way to make the matrix?

Comment: @bill There's nothing *wrong* with it, but the `Map` and `Times` operations are not needed, hence "wasteful" -- it seems pragmatically better to me to use `ConstantArray[lst, Length@lst - 1]`.

Comment: Nice! So you could just say: ConstantArray[lst, Length[lst] - 1] +  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {# - 1, #} &@ Length[lst]]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure, I just didn't want to copy you (already upvoted your answer, of course)... and maybe `Outer` is helpful because you can generalize it to construct other matrices.