# Efficient method to generate Tridiagonal 50 by 50 Matrix?

Tags: matrix

I'm looking to generate a tridiagonal 50x50 matrix, ideally without using loops. Suggestions on most efficient code for this?

Comment: DiagonalMatrix[list,k]

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of: [(13004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13004) -- please review that question and if you feel this is *not* a duplicate explain why.

Comment: Your question is [closed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because its a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) , probably you should read the policy about that.

Answer (score 8):

As Gregory Rut mentioned, `DiagonalMatrix` already has built-in support for generating banded matrices from lists:

```
Inner[DiagonalMatrix, RandomInteger[{0, 5}, #] & /@ {49, 50, 49}, {-1, 0, 1}]
```

which yields the following (when `ArrayPlot` is applied):

[image]

Comment: I just start writing that `Inner` will be more elegant then explicit sum! :)

Comment: @ybeltukov I believe a disadvantage of `Inner` is that more memory will be used.

Answer (score 7):

```
diag = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], #] & /@ {49, 50, 49};
m = SparseArray[Inner[Rule, {Band[{1, 2}], Band[{1, 1}], Band[{2, 1}]}, diag, List]]

MatrixPlot[m, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

**Timings:** for a 50X50 matrix the timings of two methods based on `Band` and `DiagonalMatrix` are both `0`. For larger matrices, `Band` is much faster:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2];
f1 = SparseArray[Inner[Rule, {Band[{1, 2}], Band[{1, 1}], Band[{2, 1}]}, #, List]] &;
f2 = Inner[DiagonalMatrix, #, {1, 0, -1}] &;
functions = {f1, f2};

testdata1 = RandomReal[5, #] & /@ {49, 50, 49};
testdata2 = RandomReal[5, #] & /@ {499, 500, 499};
testdata3 = RandomReal[5, #] & /@ {4999, 5000, 4999};
testdata4 = RandomReal[5, #] & /@ {9999, 10000, 9999};

(Equal @@ (Through@functions@#)) & /@ {testdata1, testdata2, testdata3, testdata4}
(* {True,True,True, True} *)

timings = Outer[N[First[AbsoluteTiming[#@#2;]], 5] &, 
                functions, {testdata1, testdata2, testdata3, testdata4}, 1];
TableForm[timings, TableHeadings -> {{Band, DiagonalMatrix},
                                     {"n = 50", "n = 500", "n = 5000", "n = 10000"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `Band` is not so efficient. For example, `f3 = Inner[DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@#, #2] &, #, {1, 0, -1}] &` is [10 times faster](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N4IzX.png).

Comment: @ybeltukov, really nice! I suggest you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Done! I went further :)

Comment: @ybeltukov and kguler: I marked this question as a duplicate.  Please review my action.  If you disagree or feel another action should be taken let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i agree. Btw, do you remember if the linked q/a was on the `Related` list on the right before you linked to it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check, I just remember the prior question.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my expanded response to kguler.

I noticed that usually `Band` is less effective then `DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray` or manual constructing of the resulting `SparseArray`

```
f1 = SparseArray[Inner[Rule, {Band[{1, 2}], Band[{1, 1}], Band[{2, 1}]}, #, List]] &;
f2 = Inner[DiagonalMatrix, #, {1, 0, -1}] &;;
f3 = Inner[DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@#, #2] &, #, {1, 0, -1}] &;
f4 = SparseArray[Join[Transpose@{Most@#, Rest@#}, Transpose@{#, #}, 
        Transpose@{Rest@#, Most@#}] &@Range@Length@#[[2]] -> Join @@ #] &;
f5 = With[{n = Length@#[[2]]}, SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {n, n}, 0.,
      {1,
       {Join[{0}, Range[2, 3 n - 3, 3], {3 n - 2}],
        Transpose@{Flatten[Transpose@Range[{0, 1, 2}, {n - 1, n, n + 1}]][[2 ;; -2]]}},
       Flatten[Transpose@{Prepend[#[[3]], 0.], #[[2]], Append[#[[1]], 0.]}][[2 ;; -2]]
       }}] &;
functions = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

testdata = RandomReal[5, #] & /@ {# - 1, #, # - 1} & /@ {50, 500, 5000, 10000};

(Equal @@ (Through@functions@#)) & /@ testdata
(* {True, True, True, True} *)


timings = Outer[N[First[AbsoluteTiming[#@#2;]], 5] &, functions, testdata, 1];
TableForm[timings, TableHeadings -> {{"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"}, {"n = 50", 
    "n = 500", "n = 5000", "n = 10000"}}]
```

[image]

Functions:

1. kguler's solution with `SparseArray` and `Band`
2. DumpsterDoofus's `DiagonalMatrix` with dense matrices
3. `DiagonalMatrix` with `SparseArray`
4. Manual creating of `Sparse array` with `SparseArray[indexes -> values]`
5. Completely manual creating of `SparseArray` as `SparseArray[Automatic, dimensions, defaultElement, {1, {splitting, columns}, values}]`. You can learn this format by investigating `InputForm` of any available `SparseArray`.

Comment: So the most ridiculously complex and labored solution is the fastest? Just avoid functions that are supposed to be optimized for this? Yikes!